# Game will Only Render one Enemy

Tags: java, render, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make is so that multiple squares appear on the level screen. For some reason the only square it renders will be the last one in the order I type it in. Been at it for 2 hours and is extremely annoying. Any help would be awesome and greatly appreciated.

```
public class Level1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    LevelRender render;
    static Square square;

    static Player player;
    static Square squares;
    public static Timer timer;
    boolean fail, Over, Reset = false, create = false;
    static int enemyCount = 5;

    static int eX = 200, eY, z;

    ArrayList <Enemys> squareList = new ArrayList();

    public static Level1 level;

    ImageIcon Level1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing52\\src\\testing52\\Level1.png");

    public Level1(Player player){        
        timer = new Timer(50,this);
        render = new LevelRender();        
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1000,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(render);
        addKeyListener(this);        
        this.player = player; 
        timer.start();    
        player.x = 0;
        player.y = 387;
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g){        
         g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);        
        if(!fail){            
            Level1.paintIcon(MainMenu.level1, g, -4, -25);        
            player.GameCount = 1;
            player.render(g);        
            square = new Square(50,397);
            squares = new Square(200,397);        
            square.render(g);
            squares.render(g);   
            reset();   
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 30));        
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("Health:"), 40, 80);
            //lots of other string
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 15));        
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("Level:"), 900, 20);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("1"), 950, 20);        
        }

        if(fail){            
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 500);        
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 50));        
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("You Have Failed"), 200, 150);        
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 50));
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("Press ENTER to Continue"), 120, 220);            
        }

        if(enemyCount == 0){        
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 500);        
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 50));        
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("You Won"), 200, 150);        
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 50));
            g.drawString(String.valueOf("Press ENTER to Continue"), 120, 220);     
        }        
    }

    public void createEnemys(){        
         for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
             eX += 50;
             //squares = new Enemys(player, eX, 397);
             squareList.add(squares);
             create = true;
         }
    }

    public void update(){        
        player.update();      
        if(!create){
            createEnemys();
        }
        if(Player.health <= 0){            
             fail = true;
             Over = true;
             Player.health = 10;             
        }        
        if(enemyCount == 0){            
             fail = false;
             Over = true;
        }
        System.out.println(Enemys.health + " , " + enemyCount + " , " + squareList.get(3).x  );        
     }

     public void reset(){        
         if(Reset){
             enemyCount = 5; 
             Reset = false;
            create = false;
         }        
     }



     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
         update();
         render.repaint();
    }
}
```

...................

```
public class Enemys {

public static int health, damage,x,y;  
static boolean hit;
static int count;

public Enemys(int x, int y){     
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void hit(){        
    if(Player.x == x)
    {  
        Player.health -= damage;
    }
} 

public void update(){
    hit();
}

public void hello(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}

public void render(Graphics g){}
}
```

.......................

```
public class Square extends Enemys {

static int count;
static boolean hit;

public Square(int x, int y){
    super(x,y);
    damage = 1;
    health = 30;        
}

public void render(Graphics g){        
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);        
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(x, y - 20, (50*(health / 30)), 7);      
}

public void update(){        
    x += 1;        
}  

}
```

........................

```
public class LevelRender extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    MainMenu.level1.render((Graphics2D)g);
}
}
```

...................

Comment: can you reduce your code to the relevant parts? (only rendering parts are interesting)

Comment: Yes Reposted it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847142/only-one-object-will-render-to-screen